# Possible orders of permutations of $11$ symbols

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, permutations

Which of the following numbers can be orders of permutations $\alpha$ of $11$ symbols such that it does not fix any symbol ?
$1.$ $18$,
$2.$ $30$,
$3.$ $15$,
$4.$ $28$

Answer (score 4):

A permutation $\pi$ can always be written as product of disjoint cycles
$$
\pi=c_1\cdot\ldots\cdot c_k
$$
and then the order of $\pi$ is the lcm of the lengths of the cycles $c_1,\dots,c_k$.

Thus you are looking for partitions
$$
11=\ell_1+\dots+\ell_k
$$
with $\ell_i\geq2$ for all $i$ such that $lcm(\ell_1,...,\ell_k)$ is some specified value.

For instance $11=5+6$ proves that there's a permutation as required of order 30.

Try to work out the other values by yourself!

Comment: yes 18,24,28,30 are the possible orders ,thank you very much.

Comment: what about $15$???????

Comment: @TaxiDriver : $11=5+3+3$ and $lcm(5,3,3)=15$.